# Unattended upgrade changes the linux-azure kernel to generic

Tags: kernel, unattended-upgrades

I installed linux-azure kernel on my Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa VMS that run on hypervs.

The problem is I also have unattended upgraded configured and I noticed it upgrades the kernel to linux-generic instead of updating the linux-azure already installed. So I end up with a machine with linux-generic at next reboot:

```
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-37-generic Wed Jun 24 13:08   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-37-generic Wed Jun 24 13:07 - 13:08  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-37-generic Wed Jun 24 13:03 - 13:07  (00:03)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-37-generic Wed Jun 24 11:52 - 12:18  (00:26)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-1016-azure Wed Jun 24 11:46 - 11:52  (00:05)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-1016-azure Wed Jun 24 08:56 - 11:46  (02:50)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-1016-azure Wed Jun 24 08:50 - 08:53  (00:03)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-37-generic Wed Jun 24 08:44 - 08:50  (00:05)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-37-generic Wed Jun 24 08:40 - 08:44  (00:03)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-37-generic Tue Jun 23 18:18 - 08:40  (14:21)
```

Any clue of why is this happening and how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `linux-azure` meta package to get updates on the `azure` kernel.

You have `linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic` that pull `generic` kernels.

The system will boot with the kernel with the highest number by default. If you want to boot automatically with `azure` kernels, you'll have to remove `generic` kernels.